# Can HttpWebRequest Be Used To Populate a Model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, httpwebrequest

I am wondering if HttpWebRequest can be used to fill a MVC model? I am trying to build a MVC 4 application where I take data from a college course listing page and massage it in a few different ways in my View. The examples that I have been seeing around have all taken a response stream and returned a string or have not been formatted for MVC (using console.write). Also, as far as I understand, the data as its being returned isn't in a JSON or XML format. Here is my controller so far...

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    string postData = "semester=20143Fall+2013+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++&courseid=&subject=IT++INFORMATION+TECHNOLOGY&college=&campus=1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5%2C6%2C7%2C9%2CA%2CB%2CC%2CI%2CL%2CM%2CN%2CP%2CQ%2CR%2CS%2CT%2CW%2CU%2CV%2CX%2CZ&courselevel=&coursenum=&startTime=0600&endTime=2359&days=ALL&All=All+Sections";
    byte[] dataArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (postData);
    HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www3.mnsu.edu/courses/selectform.asp");
    myRequest.Method = "POST";
    myRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    myRequest.ContentLength = dataArray.Length;
    using (WebResponse response = myRequest.GetResponse())
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            //insert into a model? Maybe?
        }
    }
    return View();
}
```

If HttbWebRequest can't be used, is there a way that would work? Or am I completely heading in the wrong direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can using HttpWebRequest and WebResponse to get stream from your college course's web site. Then use [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to parse scrap in the stream and insert your desired value into model